# Logstash create new json from existing json

Tags: logstash, logstash-filter

I am getting data in this format:

```
{
    "a": "1",
    "b": "2"
}
```

I want it to changes to:

```
{
    data: {
        "a": "1",
        "b": "2"
    }
}
```

I can change it using the mutate filter:

```
mutate {
     rename => {
        "[a]" => "[data][a]"
        "[b]" => "[data][b]"
    }
}
```

But here I have to rename each field individually.

Is there a way I can move the entire incoming message inside data field, something like:

```
rename => {"[entite_message]" => "[data][entire_message]"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Events API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-api.html) and the [ruby filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-ruby.html) to achieve this.

Adding the below ruby block should do the trick.

```
ruby {
    code => '
        # Move everything to data
        event.set("data", event.to_hash)

        # Remove fields other than data
        fields = event.to_hash.keys
        fields.each{|field|
            if (field != "data")
                event.remove(field)
            end
        }
    '
}
```